# Java: Is there a tool available that can allow me input, store, and evaluate math formulas?

Tags: java, math, formulas

Even something very rudimentary is fine.  Like entering and evaluating something like x+1, where x is a variable I get to specify.

I was thinking of writing my own using Strings for each formula, regex for parsing them, etc., but let's assume my goal is to be as lazy as I can possibly get away with, and that if there's another option (especially a formal one), I'd rather try to use that instead, first.

Is there anything out there that does something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think about using [scripting](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/) from Java 6. The reference JDK comes with a JavaScript implementation, and you can plug in other languages too.

Comment: That could possibly work, but that might be too much power for what I need.

Anything simpler than that?

Comment: Well, where are you drawing the line at what level of power you need? :-)

Comment: Well I'm not really drawing a line unless it gets performance prohibitive down the road.  I guess I'll just do it this way, then.

Comment: If you care about performance, then you should download the Rhino engine from https://scripting.dev.java.net/ (since Rhino has a bytecode compiler---but the version bundled with JDK has the compiler stripped out).

Comment: BTW it's easy to write your own engine, just use the code from that site as a template (go to the CVS section, and check out the code using user "guest"---no password needed).

Comment: Scripting is great, but doesn't it have security issues?

Comment: I'll be careful.  I'm not that dumb. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I know the following libraries:

- [Symja Parser](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) (GPL License) supports Mathematica like syntax
- [Jep - Java Math Expression Parser](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) (commercial - older versions under GNU Public License?)
- [JFormula](http://www.japisoft.com/formula/) (commercial)
- [MathEval - Math Expression Evaluator](http://softwaremonkey.org/code/MathEval/index.html) (public domain and very small footprint)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) with success a couple of years ago and it still seems to be actively developed. I believe they had a more permissive license back in those days, but it's probably cheaper than coding it yourself (depending on your exact needs and skills).

Comment: Interesting.  If this fits better, this is what I might use.  Looking into it now.

Comment: Oh jeez!  That's a hell of a license!  I think I'll just stick with scripting, then, since what I need done is pretty rudimentary (for the time being).

Comment: JEP used to be GPL. You can still download the GPL version here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/

Answer (score 1):

I've built a java library to do exactly this as a learning example for Lex/YACC, for myself. It was incorporated into a larger project, where it seems to work well. Were I to start the larger project again, I'd follow the advice above and use the Java scripting engine.

Comment: Yeah I agree.  And especially since a license for JEP would run at around 500$. :P

Answer (score 1):

You could try [LibFormula](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=51669&package_id=277201), a formula eavluation library that's based on OpenDocument's OpenFormula standard.

OpenFormula was written for spreadsheet applications and uses a syntax close to Excel-formulas. More info can be found in the [Pentaho-Wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/Formula+Expressions)

Sample:

```
=[x]+1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check out **[exp4j](http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j/index.html)** which i released under the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html). it implements dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm, and works well with multivariable functions like `f(x,foo)=log(foo^(x^-1))`

- [Demo applet](http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j-demo/demo.html)
- [Download](http://objecthunter.congrace.de/tinybo/blog/articles/86)

Answer (score 0):

Some may be interested in a new tool called [formula4j](http://www.formula4j.com/).

It's commercial, so it's not for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/)?

> MathML is a low-level specification for describing mathematics as a basis for machine to machine communication which provides a much needed foundation for the inclusion of mathematical expressions in Web pages. It is also important in publishing workflows for science and technology and wherever mathematics has to be handled by software. The new version brings, for instance, improvements for accessibility of mathematics, and for formulas in languages written from right to left. The basic markup remains the same, as the community have seven years of experience with it.

Comment: I'll definitely look into this later on.

Comment: I thought MathML is just for marking up mathematical expressions, not evaluating them.

Comment: Yeah.  XML.  Not what I need unless I start going in a new direction with my project.  Still, it's nice to know about.