# Java - Generate Code depending on userinput, compile and run it during runtime?

Tags: java, math, code-injection, dynamically-generated

In a previous project, in another language (SAP ABAP), i had to program a calculator. A colleague gave me the advice, that all programming languages are able to do mathematical calculation by its own. So i took the user input, a mathematical expression, converted it during runtime into executable code and run it. I didn't have to worry about any mathematical rules like multiplication before addition.

Is such a way, of generating executable code during runtime depending on userinputs also possible in java and if how ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/403346/24819